# Given the person is the size of an average male, how much force would have to be exerted to level a skyscraper in one punch

Tags: technology, hard-science

Now this is for a video on my channel, I'll get that out of the way now. I love gaming, science, and physics.
I recently started to try and figure out how strong the doomfist (Overwatch) would have to be to level a skyscraper.

I got this idea from this video here: https://youtu.be/FqnKB22pOC0

I spent a lot of time going over frame by frame on certain parts of this and doing a some research on the Internet, this is some of what I found:

The doomfist is a gauntlet about 2-3 average male fists wide. It appears to be operated with some sort of batteries on both sides (Hence the fact that on impact the type of blast wave appears to be electrical, and why it sparks after being used. The user, the scourge, most likely was trained by an organization known as Tallon, meaning he has training in fighting. I compared his punch to be compared to the boxer British boxer Ricky "The Hitman" Hatton (ex-welterweight champ), who had an average punching speed of 11 mps (25 mph).

The Term skyscraper is any building 50 meters(164 feet) and above.

Most Skyscrapers have a framework made of steel or reinforced concrete with a curtain wall made of glass or polished stone.

I clearly saw some type of blast-wave come from the impact hitting widowmaker. (I have ruled out explosion, EMP, and I'm doubting shockwave.) The wave looks noticeably electrical, and after impact when the glove breaks you can clearly see electricity spark from the glove with the same hue as the wave.

Newton's third law does take effect, launching both of the back. Though you can see the boy gets launched back less by the recoil.

Arm length would depend on his height, but if we look at the scourge on the map numbani, we may get some idea of arm length. This would give us the variable distance, allowing us to plug that into our equation.

I am having trouble figuring out the actual area covered by the gauntlet in a fist. If we can find the length, from pinky knuckle to index knuckle, of an average male hand we can figure out what Length it is, but not width. Also since we are looking for how long the scourge's arm is, we find that, we get our height as well.

I decided to also try and use real world materials to try and figure out the mass. I figure to absorb some of the impact it would need some sort of vibration dampener, so I chose a martial known as sorbothane. Then considering that the glove is likely electrically charged with some sort of highly strong metal on the outside, it would need a protecting layer of something, so I guessed the black under the metal was rubber. The metal and battery are the parts giving me a problem.

D/T=S (Distance/Time=Speed) from the kid punching to the time of impact it takes about 0.4 seconds reach her, and I'm going to estimate the kids arm from shoulder to wrist to be about 2.5 ft-3 ft. now if we plug it in: 2.5/0.4=6.25 or 3/0.4=7.5 now this is far from 100% accurate, but it is the closest we are going to get without precise image showing how close they are.

We are going to use this < to show the change in and the amount in the next equation

M*A=F (Mass*Acceleration=Force)

Comment: This may benefit from a a more concise question. A simple "assuming a normal sized human, how strong would their punch need to be to level a skyscraper (without the use of explosives)?" would suffice. It seems this question was inspired by a video. If so, can we see the video in question? Additionally, it looks like you have some of the needed skills to answer this yourself, although I'm sure some people here wouldn't mind throwing out their solutions.

Comment: I like this place more than Reddit, there's actual constructive criticism and help. XD

Comment: I'll edit this and try and make my question more clear. I'll link to the video. I do have some of the skills needed, but in the end I'm still a 14 year old teaching this to himself. I just am seeking some help in the end. I'd love theories from others though! Thank you for your criticism, I'll take it into mind.

Comment: Also how do I get my question of hold? I edited it.

Comment: @XxCasualnessxX The question is currently being reviewed for reopening (and currently has two reopen votes, requiring three more to be reopened). You have done what you can for the moment, now you simply have to wait for the community to have their say in reopening the question. Such things usually happen in a matter of hours on this site, so just be patient a little longer. If it hasn't been reopened in 2-3 days, then you may want to bring it up and ask for further feedback either in [chat] or on [meta] (make sure to link to the question!), but not really earlier than that.

Comment: This will come down to the nature of the building--how many support columns it has.  You will at best take out one line of columns, if that's not enough to collapse it you fail no matter how hard you punch.

Comment: All is not lost, though--such a punch will carry energy far in excess of how fast it can be dissipated and thus you will get a blast wave.  If that energy is high enough you can blow it up.  Beware that blowing up support columns requires very high energy densities as we saw with the Twin Towers and Oklahoma City bombings.  Even with a truck full of explosives McVeigh only got 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

## It is not a matter of force

Your question has very little to do with Newtonian physics because this question is not a matter of how hard you strike, but **where** you strike.

Your fist will punch a hole wherever it hits if you just put enough momentum into it, but that is pointless if all you do is — for instance — punch through the windows. Also if you punch hard enough, you will just make a hole as large as the fist, and not much more.

This video shows clearly what happens when something hits metal fast. Either the target holds and splats the bullet, or the bullet punches a rather clean hole right through.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfDoQwIAaXg

As 9/11 demonstrated: the force of the planes smashing into the buildings did not bring them down. Flight 11 hit at 404 mph / 748 kph, and flight 175 at 590 mph / 950 km/h. But it was the fires that weakened the buildings that caused the collapse.

So your question is not about how hard you hit, but in what places.

Comment: I do know this and figured you'd have to target the framework. That's why I stated what the framework is made of, I guess I should have made it more clear. Sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: @XxCasualnessxX Well your entire post is, I am sorry to say, extremely confusing. You are just piling statements on each other and there is no clear thread of reasoning anywhere. One thing is very clear from the outset though: one punch will not do the trick. Your boxer will have to run around and punch several places.

Comment: Don't be sorry, it shows me where I need to improve and explain more. But that's why it's important, is because to be 100% true, a human being shouldn't be able to exert that much force. But I'm trying to figure out how it could be done in one punch, the cause that amount of force in the amount of time would have on the wearer and surrounding area.

Comment: Also, I just pulled parts of what we found from the Reddit post I had made. Sorry for the just throwing out the statements

Comment: Still won't work. A properly designed skyscraper can't be brought down by a single point of failure, even if it's a column